# how can I check if there is no winner in a tic tac toe game visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

This is a User vs User Tic Tac Toe game; how can I implement a loop to check whether there is a TIE in the game instead of using if/else statements?

If not, is there a way to make this code less long with loops?

This is my code so far. The game accurately checks if there is a winner but is missing to know when there is no winner.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim choice As Boolean
Dim playerXwins, playerOwins As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Panel1.Enabled = False
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = False
    Button3.Enabled = False
    Button4.Enabled = False
    Button5.Enabled = False
    Button6.Enabled = False
    Button7.Enabled = False
    Button8.Enabled = False
    Button9.Enabled = False
    ExitButton.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub ExitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub PlayButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PlayButton.Click

    PlayButton.Enabled = False
    Panel1.Enabled = True
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Button2.Enabled = True
    Button3.Enabled = True
    Button4.Enabled = True
    Button5.Enabled = True
    Button6.Enabled = True
    Button7.Enabled = True
    Button8.Enabled = True
    Button9.Enabled = True
    ExitButton.Enabled = True

End Sub

Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click

    If choice = False Then
        CType(sender, Button).Text = "X"
        choice = True
    Else
        CType(sender, Button).Text = "O"
        choice = False
    End If
    ChoosingWinner()

End Sub

Private Sub ChoosingWinner()

    If Button1.Text = "X" And Button2.Text = "X" And Button3.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won this Round")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins


    ElseIf Button1.Text = "X" And Button4.Text = "X" And Button7.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won Round")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins

    ElseIf Button1.Text = "X" And Button5.Text = "X" And Button9.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button2.Text = "X" And Button5.Text = "X" And Button8.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button3.Text = "X" And Button6.Text = "X" And Button9.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button3.Text = "X" And Button5.Text = "X" And Button7.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button4.Text = "X" And Button5.Text = "X" And Button6.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button7.Text = "X" And Button8.Text = "X" And Button9.Text = "X" Then
        MsgBox("Player X Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerXwins = playerXwins + 1
        Label2.Text = playerXwins
    End If

    If Button1.Text = "O" And Button2.Text = "O" And Button3.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    If Button1.Text = "O" And Button4.Text = "O" And Button7.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    If Button1.Text = "O" And Button5.Text = "O" And Button9.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    If Button2.Text = "O" And Button5.Text = "O" And Button8.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If


    If Button3.Text = "O" And Button6.Text = "O" And Button9.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    If Button3.Text = "O" And Button5.Text = "O" And Button7.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    If Button4.Text = "O" And Button5.Text = "O" And Button6.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If


    If Button7.Text = "O" And Button8.Text = "O" And Button9.Text = "O" Then
        MsgBox("Player O Won!")
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""
        playerOwins = playerOwins + 1
        Label1.Text = playerOwins
    End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: you have all the *win* scenario's, so: `If Not` win `And` no buttons left `Then` tie. Maybe you can use a counter, or check the status of the buttons to see no more actions are valid.

Comment: Just a small tip .. to shorten the code, use the DRY principle - "Dont Repeat Yourself" .. Write a sub that clears the buttons, and rather than repeatedly write all that code, just call the sub  :-)

Comment: Also and still no offence, this code is rather a good example of why you shouldn't use controls as the primary store for your data. If you use an array of strings, you could just iterate across each row, and check each of the two diagonals much more easily. You would of course need to write a bit of code to update the buttons, but that would just be another 11 lines of code.

Comment: Have a look at this code that I've put in a text file to check if a game has either not finished/stalemate/won. Imagine a 2d array of strings `Dim gameGrid(2,2) As String` The code in the text file should either return "N" for an incomplete game, "S" for a stalemate game or the player "X" or "O" of the winner ( or whatever character you are using) - Heres a link to the text file on my google drive account - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z-a_ot11PHe-AZsq4hwo65k48Yocbpie

Comment: @DavidWilson Thanks so much, I did take a look at it. I will do an array instead of relying on the buttons so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn all of your `If`s into an `If-Elif` structure, and in the final `Elif` (after all of the checks to see whether someone has won), check if all of the buttons have been used, and if they have, then there's a tie.